# Adding button to lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

I am adding UIelement by using following code

```
legendBox =  chart[unique].addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column.setBackground( UIBackgrounds.Rectangle ))
.setPosition({ x: 0, y: 100 })
.setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftTop)
```

Right now I am able to add series to it by following code

```
entry = legendBox.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox);
series.attach(entry);
```

Instead , can I add the button with some value ? On clicking of that button I need call an function with that value.

For example if I add button with value

```
<button val="22">Click<button>
```

Now when i click that button , I need a callback function returning 22.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `entry` variable is of type [`UICheckBox`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/uicheckbox.html).

To apply a custom action when clicking it, the [`onSwitch`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/uicheckbox.html#onswitch) method should do it.

`series.attach(entry);` is only required if you want the button to hide/restore the series, you can remove this code if you want that **only** your custom action is triggered.

```
entry = legendBox.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
entry.onSwitch((_, checked) => {
   console.log('clicked', checked)
})
```

See also `UIElementBuilders.ButtonBox` if you want to add automatic bounce-back.

```
entry = legendBox.addElement(UIElementBuilders.ButtonBox)
entry.onSwitch((_, checked) => {
   if (checked) {
       console.log('button pressed')
   }
})
```

Comment: No I need button , look at https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-audio/ ..

Comment: You can inspect the code in that showcase https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-showcase-audio

The "Reset Spectum Max" button there is made with `UIElementBuilders.ButtonBox` like I described. Other kinds of buttons, you'll need to implement with HTML.

Comment: I am trying multi chart layouts , so html is not possible.will try Buttonbox .. onswitch works for buttonbox too ?

Comment: `onSwitch` works in same way for ButtonBox, but you'll probably want to add if check to only act when the button is activated. I edited the code snippet.

I don't really understand why HTML would not be possible, though...

Comment: Hi , suppose I have 6 charts in 1 layout ,, how to I add html buttons of top left in each (0,0) , can we get html X &  Y position of all 6 charts via lightning charts ?

Comment: Separating each chart into its own <div> sounds like the easiest approach there. Then you can add the button inside the same <div> that contains each chart.

Comment: hmm, but dashboard gives lots of features like resizing charts etc..is there any other tweaks to get title position or legendbox position in HTML x.y ? so i can place my html somewhere around those.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be possible - could you open a question specifically on this ("how to place HTML elements in dashboard relative to charts"), and I will then respond there?

Comment: Hi , I have opened new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242571/finding-charts-position-from-dashboard-in-lightningchart