# Finding Charts position from dashboard in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

I have a dashboard like this

```
db = lightningChart().Dashboard({
    numberOfRows: 3,
    numberOfColumns: 2,
    theme: them[theme],

    
})
```

Here I am adding 6 different charts

```
  chart[name] = [];
    chart[name] = db.createChartXY({
        columnIndex: ci,
        rowIndex: ri,
        columnSpan: cs,
        rowSpan: rs,

    })
```

Now How do I get the position of this charts in html page , So I can add html buttons on the top Left of 6 different charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

locations in LCJS can be translated back to document coordinate system using `engineLocation2Client` function.

In order to translate a location relative to a chart to the document, you can utilize one of the two coordinate systems of charts:

1. [uiScale](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#uiscale) (percentage based coordinate system), [0,0]=bottom left, [100,100]=top right.
2. [pixelScale](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#pixelscale) (pixel based coordinate system), [0,0]=bottom left.

The actual translation is done like this:

```
const locationUiScale = { x: 0, y: 100 } // Top left.
const locationEngine = translatePoint(locationUiScale, chart.uiScale, chart.engine.scale)
const locationDocument = chart.engine.engineLocation2Client(locationEngine.x, locationEngine.y)
```

Afterwards, `locationDocument` should contain the X,Y coordinate on document that matches the top left corner of that particular chart.

Comment: Thank you works fine  , is there any callbacks when charts inside dashboard is resized ?

Comment: `Chart.onResize` should do
https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#onresize